# Dynamically change product title with custom text option - Magento 2

Tags: module, configurable-product, magento2.2, custom-options

My goal is to change my products title dynamically with a custom option (first name).

For an example:

[image]

Is there an extension for this? If not, how should I go about creating a module for this? 

I am fairly new to developing in Magento so bear with me on my lack of knowledge!

Comment: You want what ever customer type to Fist Name field, it is gonna change the title, is that what you want ?

Comment: @ToànTam Yes, whatever the custom types in the name field would update the product title.

Comment: So Just use javascript to handle that. Listen to on change event of textbox and update the title acorddingly.

Comment: Where do I add my javascript code to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

please use pio customizedTitle module from magento marketplace.